# Pass by reference, source being modified mid-operation

Tags: c++, matrix, reference

I'm working on a program that solves a system of equations in matrix form via Gaussian elimination.  However, I ran into an interesting issue:  If my arithmetic operators pass by reference, normalization of rows gives incorrect results.

In my implementation, a Matrix is comprised of multiple Vectors, so row operations are just vector arithmetic.  Here are the relevant functions:

**Vector:**

```
T& operator[] (const int i);
const T& operator[] (const int i) const;
Vector<T>& operator/=(const T& rhs);

template<class T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator/=(const T& rhs)
{
  if (rhs == 0)
  {
    throw DivideByZeroException();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
  {
    _data[i] /= rhs;
  }
  return *this;
}
```

**Matrix:**

```
Vector<T>& operator[] (const int i);
const Vector<T>& operator[] (const int i) const;
```

(This way, a single [] is used to access a row, and double [][] is used to access an element.)

Now here is the line that causes the problem:

```
mat[i] /= mat[i][i];
```

The problem here is that this operation modifies `mat[i][i]` at some point, and then uses the modified value since `operator/=` uses pass by reference.

***Question***: Would it be better to change the operator (and all similar operators) to pass by value, or just change the line that is causing the problem?  Is it assumed that all operators will be by reference, making lines like the one above bad in general?

Comment: I think your line `mat[i] /= mat[i][i];` breaks the fundamental language rule __no multiple assignation between 2 sequence points__. well its not a rule, just an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think I'm going to make my comment a full answer, the problem comes not from the implementation of your `/=` operator, but very much on the caller line itsel. Like I said, this is not supposed to give a predictable (legal) result. Because the language says so very clearly in the standard, and gives the `i = i++ + ++i;` as an example line of this fact.

So my suggestion is don't try to make this thing work as a special gesture of your good will for your clients, because clients who do this break a more important contract than just your class specifications.

Comment: Exactly what two modifications do you think are occurring unsequenced to a single object in this program?

Comment: @Casey: this is not a bad question you raise. It asks for a decomposition. I thought after quick skimming that mat[i][i] is modified when its being divided by itself during the divison of the matrix line. So it makes it incorrect because it depends if the divisor is the direct matrix component or a temporary copy of it. But if we think of it like `x /= x` being `x = x / x` you are right by pointing that it is infact legit regarding sequence rules.